# Why don't my karma tests fail when the unit test has a parse error?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

We currently use karma + jasmine to run unit tests. When there is a bug in the product code, this works great. However, if someone makes a typo in a unit test file, then it causes all of the tests to abort, and more importantly, the return code is 0 so our CI server thinks it passed:

```
START:
14 05 2016 18:28:03.258:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.22 server started at http://localhost:9876/
14 05 2016 18:28:03.264:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
14 05 2016 18:28:03.917:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#qLf4mgQG51O8hmSlAAAA with id 66915424
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  SyntaxError: Expected token '}'
  at <filename removed>.spec.js:46

Finished in 0.311 secs / 0 secs

SUMMARY:
✔ 0 tests completed
```

How can I configure Karma to either just fail that one test (ideal), or at the very least throw an error code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an FYI to anyone who reads this, the latest karma runner no longer seems to exhibit this flaw, so upgrading may help. Happy coding!